# "cat a | cat b" ignoring contents of a

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

The formal definition of pipe states that the STDOUT of the left file will be immediately piped to the STDIN of the right file.I have two files, `hello.txt` and `human.txt`.  `cat hello.txt` returns `Hello` and `cat human.txt` returns `I am human`.Now if I do `cat hello.txt | cat human.txt`, shouldn't that return `Hello I am human`?Instead I'm seeing `command not found`.I am new to shell scripting.Can someone explain?

Comment: This post belongs on [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/756158/what-does-the-linux-pipe-symbol-do).

Comment: `human.txt is not a command` is certainly not what I'd expect -- the output *should* be only `I am human`. Can you provide exact, tested reproduction steps?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy See the edit.Sorry for confusion. Btw great explanation and I liked it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Background: A pipe arranges for the output of the command on the left (that is, contents written to FD 1, stdout) to be delivered as input to the command on the right (on FD 0, stdin). It does this by connecting the processes with a "pipe", or FIFO, and executing them at the same time; attempts to read from the FIFO will wait until the other process has written something, and attempts to write to the FIFO will wait until the other process is ready to read.

---

```
cat hello.txt | cat human.txt
```

...feeds the content of `hello.txt` into the stdin of `cat human.txt`, but *`cat human.txt` isn't reading from its stdin*; instead, it's been directed by its command line arguments to read only from `human.txt`.

Thus, that content on the stdin of `cat human.txt` is ignored and never read, and `cat hello.txt` receives a SIGPIPE when `cat human.txt` exits, and thereafter exits as well.

---

```
cat hello.txt | cat - human.txt
```

...by contrast will have the second `cat` read first from stdin (you could also use `/dev/stdin` in place of `-` on many operating systems, including Linux), then from a file.

Comment: What do you think of using xargs in this situation (eg. `cat ./*txt | xargs`)?

Comment: I think it's unlikely to be a good idea. The default behavior of `xargs` -- of calling `echo` -- puts us in a place where all the unfortunate misbehaviors of `echo` are relevant, not to mention the surprising corner-case behaviors of `xargs` without either the `-d` or `-0` extensions.

Comment: I was thinking sort of along the same lines; I guess the only upside is that the output is on a single line.

Comment: it's only on a single line if the amount of content is short enough to fit on `ARG_MAX`. Otherwise it'll spill into multiple `echo` invocations.

Comment: ...to put contents from all files whose names end in a `.txt` on a single line without those caveats, consider: `cat -- *.txt | xargs -d $'\n' printf '%s '; echo`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pipe them rather you can read from multiple file like below which will in-turn concatenate the content of both file content

```
cat hello.txt human.txt
```

`|` generally used when you want to fed output of first command to the second command in pipe. In this case specifically your second command is reading from a file and thus don't need to be piped. If you want to you can do like

```
echo "Hello" | cat - human.txt
```

Comment: But I want to know the use of pipe anyway.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, from which answer do you think I have copied? please link that as well along with your comment.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, nope you got it totally wrong. not even a single character copied from your answer though the last example is taken from `cat` man page. I didn't copied an answer without attribution when was in 100 rep ... now it's out of the question. Think once before posting such a comment.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, still in doubt ... I believe you can check edit history. isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116832/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-rahul).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, no need ... I have flagged your comment ... lets mods take a decision on this.

Comment: Fair enough. I think my words were tempered enough (making it clear that I was claiming only nonliteral adaptation) to be truthful, accurate, and able to survive moderator review. (I now somewhat regret having deleted the initial comment myself).

Answer (score 0):

First thing the command will not give an error it will print I m human i.e the contents of human.txt

Yeah you are right about pipe definition , but on the right side of pipe there should be some command.
If the command is for receiving the input and providing the output than it will give you output,otherwise the command will do its own behaviour

But here there is a command i.e cat human.txt on the right side but it will print its own contents and does no operation on the received input .

And also this error comes when when you write like 
cat hello.txt | human.txt
bash will give you this error :
human.txt: command not found